# Tensorflow giving NaN histogram error at the first hidden layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using the example: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/input_fn/boston.py

to make a test script using the exact same skeleton except I used a dataset from the UCI repository: 
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Airfoil+Self-Noise

However I keep running into a NaN histogram error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram
for: dnn/dnn/hiddenlayer_0_activation
[[Node: dnn/dnn/hiddenlayer_0_activation = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dnn/dnn
/hiddenlayer_0_activation/tag, dnn/hiddenlayer_0/hiddenlayer_0/Relu)]]
```

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import itertools

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
#import feature_column as fc

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

COLUMNS = ["freq", "angle", "chord", "velocity", "thic", "snd"]
FEATURES = ["freq", "angle", "chord", "velocity", "thic"]
LABEL = "snd"


def input_fn(data_set):
  feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values) for k in FEATURES}
  labels = tf.constant(data_set[LABEL].values)
  return feature_cols, labels


def main(unused_argv):
  # Load datasets
  training_set = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Aida\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\airfoil_train.csv", skipinitialspace=True,
                             skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
  test_set = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Aida\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\airfoil_test.csv", skipinitialspace=True,
                         skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)

  # prediction set
  prediction_set = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Aida\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\airfoil_predict.csv", skipinitialspace=True,
                               skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)

  # Feature cols
  feature_cols = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k)
                  for k in FEATURES]

  # clip the gradients using gloal norms
  #list1 = 
  #global_norm1 = tf.global_norm(list1)
  #clipper = tf.clip_by_global_norm(list1, 1,  global_norm1, name=None)

  # Build 3 layer DNN with dropout
  regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 10],
                                            model_dir="/tmp/airfoil_model",
                                            optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1, l1_regularization_strength=0.001)
                                            )

  # Fit
  regressor.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(training_set), steps=3000)

  # Score accuracy
  ev = regressor.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test_set), steps=1)
  loss_score = ev["loss"]
  print("Loss: {0:f}".format(loss_score))

  # Print out predictions
  y = regressor.predict_scores(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(prediction_set))

  # .predict() returns an iterator; convert to a list and print predictions
  predictions = list(itertools.islice(y, 10))
  print("Predictions: {}".format(str(predictions)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

I tried to change the optimizer's learning rate as you can see, I also tried gradient clipping but that put me into a whole new mess. I even created another whole skeleton using a different data but it gave me the same error. It could be the way I formatted the data set, but I followed the tutorials format almost exactly. 
(I can post images of the CSV file format if desired. I don not have enough points right now to put multiple links)

I tried the original tutorial script and it worked perfectly fine. I would like to know what the error is saying (in layman terms) and why it is happening.

EDIT:Problem was solved by removing the feature name row in the CSV file, which was the first row, however this is still concerning how I cannot put
a row with the feature names without causing a read error.

For the sake of knowledge I would still like to know why it could be happening and what the original error means

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to name the columns? Can't you just use index's if you need to do something special column-wise?

Comment: Isn't the FEATURES column basically indexing the file? From my understanding a tuple named "feature cols" is created by counting each unique name in the FEATURE list and creating an element in the tuple for each.